# check if array is equal to in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to check when my array contains certain values:

```
if( array == ["value1", "value2", "value3"] ){
    console.log('yes');
}else{
    console.log('no');
}
```

But it does not work...

---

**Update:** Thanks for help, now this is working for me:

```
if( JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(["value1", "value2", "value3"]) ){
    console.log('yes');
}else{
    console.log('no');
}
```

Comment: I've been studying functional programming and saw your question. I was curious to answer it using some techniques that are new to me. I've shared my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34256998/633183).

Comment: @naomik thanks mate!